# Dereferencing " cv::Mat* " pointer to cv::Mat to Receive Gstreamer Video and Use in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm working on receiving video stream from source. (Gazebo Simulation)
First of all, I'm succesful to receive on python side, but I want to move code C++.
This is python code:
[Python code](https://github.com/bozkurthan/PX4-Gazebo-Opencv/blob/master/opencv-gazebo.py)
Also I can easily add tracker to python by using:

```
video = Video()
frame = video.frame()
bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)
ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
```

But when I tried to same thing on C++ it's not possible to pass easily these steps. I used this code and this is working fine:
[C++ Code Gstream](https://gist.github.com/patrickelectric/5dca1cb7cef4ffa7fbb6fb70dd9f9edc#file-video_udp-cpp)

But I couldn't be able to use like opencv. Key code lines are:

```
        // Main loop
    while(1) {
        g_main_iteration(false);

        cv::Mat* frame = atomicFrame.load();

        if(frame) {
            cv::imshow("Frame", frame[0]);
            cv::waitKey(30);
        }
    }
```

When I tried to add basic text like:

```
putText(frame[0], " Hello", Point(100,20), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, Scalar(50,170,50),2);
```

I'm getting hard "Segmentation fault".

I tried also use single line to receive video normal way:

```
VideoCapture video("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=(string)BGR ! videoconvert! appsink name=sink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=1 drop=true",CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

But video couldn't be open.

Comment: If you get an error as "segmentation fault", you are not allowed to access memory which you are not allowed to or non-exist file. Just be sure about your file's path, video existence, and you are allowed to reach it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is wrong to assign Mat* pointer address to Mat variable. I used pipeline for this case.

Comment: Lack of synchronization around the lifetime of the pointer. The callback deletes the old `Mat` object and creates new one each time it's called. There's nothing preventing this from happening while the main thread is still using that particular instance.

Comment: Also, all those raw pointers are a leakfest waiting to happen. Learn about smart pointers and use them. (BTW, the proper term for what you call "converting" is "dereferencing a pointer")

Comment: That's right. I updated title as well. I'm not good at pointers. So when they come whole codes are being not understandable anymore for me :) Thx BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary anymore to convert cv::Mat* to cv::Mat. Furthermore, it's not logical.

Here is current pipeline that working without error in Gazebo Simulation:

```
VideoCapture video("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoco
```